# What is the most performant table index for a set of history records?

Tags: mysql, sql, performance, indexing

I have a simple history table that I am developing a new lookup for. I am wondering what is the best index (if any) to add to this table so that the lookups are as fast as possible.

The history table is a simple set of records of actions taken. Each action has a type and an action date (and some other attributes). Every day a new set of action records is generated by the system.

The relevant pseudo-schema is:

```
TABLE history
    id int,
    type int,
    action_date date
    ...
INDEX
    id
    ...
```

Note: the table is *not* indexed on `type` or `action_date`.

The new lookup function is intended to retrieve all the records of a specific type that occurred on a specific action date.

My initial inclination is to define a compound key consisting of both the `type` and the `action_date`.

However in my case there will be many actions with the same type and date. Further, the actions will be roughly evenly distributed in number each day.

Given all of the above: (a) is an index worthwhile; and (b) if so, what is the preferred index(es)?

I am using MySQL, but I think my question is not specific to this RDBMS.

Comment: An index on (type,action_date) (and/or (action_date,type)) would seem sensible

Comment: I would go with a compound index on date + type. The clustering factor will be really good as the data seem to be ordered by the date, so I would expect it to work well. You would have to test it though, maybe the index will have to look up a lot of nodes if the amount of data with the same date and type is very high.

Comment: If the compound index works well, you might also opt for an index only scan, by adding the other fields you want to select into the index. This way the db would not need to fetch them from the actual table. (But this is another topic I guess)

Comment: You could use some table partitioning either by type or by date. This will bring some speed to the queries. http://www.arubin.org/files/PracticalPartitioning_Webinar.pdf

Comment: @valicu2000 - a suitable index seems feasible in this case.  Therefore, partitioning is unlikely to improve performance.

Answer (score 1):

The first field on index should be the one giving you the smallest dataset for the majority of queries after the condition is applied.

Depending on your business requirements, you may request a specific date or specific date range (most likely the date range). So the date should one the last field on the index. Most likely you will always have the date condition.

A common answer is to have the (type,date) index, but you should consider just the date index if you ever query more than one type value in the query or if you have just a few types (like less than 5) and they are not evenly distributed.

For example, you have type 1 70% of the table, type 2,3,4,... is less than few percent of the table, and you often query type 1, you better have just separate date index, and type index (for cases when you query type 2,3,4,), not compound (type, date) index.

Comment: If Date is the first or only field in the index, the index b-tree will end up with worst case balance since history is always added at the end.  Better to use <type, date> if possible.

Comment: Again, (type,date) is common answer in such discussion, but the index won't be used by mysql if type value covers more 30% of records even if your date range is small as the the second field.

Comment: Perhaps to improve your answer you should mention that a history table that is indexed by date should be reindexed frequently.

Comment: John, I think adding later date values always at the end is a "natural" way to grow index and reindexing won't be ever needed.  But for (type, date) the type value is unpredicted and will you will need to reindex exactly as you explained.

Comment: @John I think you have misunderstood how a B-tree works.  A B-tree is always balanced.  That is, all branches of the tree have the same depth.  The need to reorganize an index happens because due to page splitting, index pages may end up with a lot of free space.   This problem is avoided if inserting at the end of the B-tree since one can add a new page without splitting an existing page.

Answer (score 1):

`INDEX(type, action_date)`, regardless of cardinality or distribution of either column.  Doing so will minimize the number of 'rows' of the index's BTree` that need to be looked at.  (Yes, I am disagreeing with Sergiy's Answer.)

Even for `WHERE type IN (2,3) AND action_date ...` can use that index.

For checking against a date range of, say 2 weeks, I recommend this pattern:

```
AND action_date >= '2016-10-16`
AND action_date  < '2016-10-16` + INTERVAL 2 WEEK
```

A way to see how much "work" is needed for a query:

```
FLUSH STATUS;
SELECT ...;
SHOW SESSION STATUS LIKE 'Handler%';
```

The numbers presented will give you a feel for how many index (or data) rows need to be touched.  This makes it easy to see which of two possible queries/indexes works better, even when the table is too small to get reliable timings.

Comment: As I mentioned earlier your index choice depends on actual dataset and query business patterns (typical searches). Mysql index will not be effective if the first condition is not constant. For the list of values of the first field the index will be used, but the date part of the index won't be used.

Comment: @SergiyTytarenko - When MRR was added (5.6.0? 5.6.10?), the Optimizer could use an `IN` list _and_ reach beyond it in the index.  See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/mrr-optimization.html  dave - What version are you using?

Comment: Rick, I'm using mariadb 10.0 and well aware of MRR settings and fiddlings. I would not rely on the optimizer when you are DESIGNING the table. As example, simple business query "all types for two weeks" will make full index and table scan for index (type, date).

Comment: Yes, that one needs `INDEX(date)`.

Comment: Rick, MariaDB was the first one introduced those optimizations. They are ok to quickly resolve certain query issues on existing dataset, not to design dataset. Just because you are using specific MySQL version, you would not be ok to defend (type,date) index to cover simple date range index coverage. B-tree indices do not change with MySQL version.

Comment: The overlap is:  `type IN (...) AND date = '...'` works almost equally well with either `INDEX(date, type)` or `INDEX(type, date)`

Comment: @Sergiy For a query like `type IN(...) AND date BETWEEN '...' AND '...'`, with an index on `(type, date)`, the optimizer will be able to set up multiple smaller ranges using both columns.  With an index on `(date, type)` a larger range covering the entire date range will have to be set up.  Hence, a (type, date) index may be more flexible.  However, if rows are inserted in date order, and the primary key is a monotonically increasing integer, an index on (date, type) may give better locality and better I/O efficiency if data needs to be read from disk.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, an index is worthwhile. Especially if you search for a small subset of the table.

If your search would match 20% or more of the table (approximately), the MySQL optimizer decides that the index is more trouble than it's worth, and it'll do a table-scan even if the index is available.

If you search for one specific `type` value and one specific `date` value, an index on (type, date) or an index on (date, type) is a good choice. It doesn't matter much which column you list first.

If you search for *multiple* values of type or *multiple* dates, then the order of columns matters. Follow this guide:

- The leftmost columns of the index should be the ones on which you do *equality* comparisons. An equality comparison is one that matches exactly one value (even if that value is found on many rows).

  ```
  WHERE type = 2 AND date = '2016-10-19' -- both equality
  ```
- The next column of the index can be part of a *range* comparison. A range comparison matches multiple values. For example, `>` or `IN( )` or `BETWEEN` or `!=`.

  ```
  WHERE type = 2 AND date > '2016-10-19' -- one equality, one range
  ```

  Only **one** such column benefits from an index. If you have range comparisons on multiple columns, only the first column of the index will use the index to support lookups. The subsequent column(s) will have to search through those matching rows "the hard way".

  ```
  WHERE type IN (2, 3, 4) AND date > '2016-10-19' -- multiple range
  ```
- If you sometimes search using a range condition on `type` and equality on `date`, you'll need to create a second index.

  ```
  WHERE type IN (2, 3, 4) AND date = '2016-10-19' -- make index on (date, type)
  ```

  The order of terms in your `WHERE` clause doesn't matter. The SQL query optimizer will figure that out and reorder them to match the right columns defined in an index.

Comment: Yes, that is correct, and for practical reasons, the business will want for sure to query more than one type and for sure to query the date range. That's when you will get a call from the business that your query is slow. I do think (type, date) is s trap when your data will get big. Having separate indices for date and type will benefit your dataset later and provide better coverage. Plus mysql and specifically mariadb can combine separate index results effectively.

Comment: `INDEX(type), INDEX(date)` is not as good as `INDEX(type,date), INDEX(date,type)`.  Phrased another way:  "index merge is almost never as good as a composite index".

Comment: Bill -- does the 20% "rule" apply to multi-column indexes?  My impression is that it does not.

Comment: I agree that the two composite indexes with different column order is better than two individual indexes. I've frankly never seen index-merge do anything useful.

Comment: @RickJames, I can't say that I specifically tested the 20% rule for composite indexes. It would be worth testing.

Comment: Whether an index is used or not depends on how large part of the index will have to be scanned.   Whether it is a single-column or multi-column index should not matter.    Note also that if the index is covering (i.e. all needed columns are part of the index), index may be used for larger ranges.